# Excel VBA - Cell value contains 'MIG'

Tags: excel, vba

I know theres a way to look if a cell value contains a certain string. I know some programming languages use % ... %.

```
    If shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value <> "%MIG%" Then
        shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value = shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value + "MIG"
    End If
```

I want to see if my Cell A already contains MIG, if it does it shouldn't update the value, if it doesn't contain MIG, it should update the current value with MIG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
If not shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value like "*MIG*" Then
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If InStr(0, shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value, "MIG", vbTextCompare)=0 Then
    shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value = shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value + "MIG"
End If
```